# UITableView filteredArrayUsingPredicate with multiple condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nspredicate

What I do:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"SELF.street contains[c] %@ OR SELF.id contains[c] %@", searchText];

self.filteredItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:
   [self.items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

I want to check if the given searchText is either in ID or in STREET property. STREET alone works, however as soon as I add the ID check my app crashes.

Any idea how to have both checks for ID and STREET ind the predicate?

Comment: Try to rename the field id to something else, see if it helps.

Comment: I get Can't use in/contains operator with collection 326105 (not a collection). 326105 is the value of SELF.id, I renamed it to SELF.zone but it does not help

Comment: So basically SELF.id what object is that?

Comment: @Legoless it's NSString

Comment: Are you sure? Because the code you wrote works for me.

Comment: Test if this code works for you: https://github.com/Legoless/StackOverflow/tree/master/Objective-C/PredicatesWithOR

Comment: @Legoless sorry its NSNumber... :) what do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: The most simple solution would be to make a readonly NSString property that returns string from the number. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using %@ twice, but only providing one argument, try:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
    @"SELF.street contains[c] %@ OR SELF.id contains[c] %@", searchText, searchText];
```

---

I changed ID from NSNumber to NSString. Now it works.